# Rescheduled flight

Tags: tickets

My flight from Chennai to London is rescheduled from 8 th Jan to 9 th Jan 2021. Where as my connection flight from London to Manchester is not rescheduled. What to do? How to reschedule the connecting flight?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket or did you buy the flights seperately?

Comment: And what was the reason for the first flight being rescheduled?

Comment: Also, what airline(s) are you flying on?

Answer (score 4):

If both flights are on one ticket you don't need to worry, the airline has to reschedule the connection flight too.
If you booked 2 separate tickets it's up to you to reschedule or book a new connection flight.

Answer (score 1):

For a purchase made on a single ticket, call the airline to reschedule as soon as possible. Otherwise, it will be up to you to reschedule the second flight yourself and incur an applicable penalty since both flights would not be related from a booking perspective.

Normally, when an airline reschedules a flight, they automatically reschedule connecting flights but I've seen it happen quite a few times that it either fails to reschedule or the new schedule is impossible, such as arriving at your destination *after* your return flight. It's impossible to say why that happens sometimes but is most likely a bug in a system when there are massing routing changes or cancellations at the airline or one of its partners.

You should proceed to contact them quickly because your options tend to get less desirable as people rebook their trips. It is likely your first flight will be rescheduled again if they cannot find a suitable connection which is often the case then the entire trip did not get rescheduled simultaneously.

Comment: You may also mention that, when calling to reschedule, it can be a good idea to do some research ahead of time and know what flights you want. The agent you get on the phone may be more or less motivated to find you the best rerouting, but if you know what flights you want and you tell them, they're likely to just give them to you if available.

Comment: Great point! It's good practice to know your options before calling because then you can guide the agent's search for rebooking you.